# How to optimize an df.apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in the following format.

DataFrame A:

```
DateTime            | A |
-------------------------
2020-01-01 06:34:12 | 1 |
2020-01-01 06:36:24 | 2 |
2020-01-01 06:36:28 | 3 |
...
```

DataFrame B:

```
StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | Value |
---------------------------------------------------
2020-01-01 06:30:00 | 2020-01-01 06:35:00 | 1.5   |
2020-01-01 06:35:00 | 2020-01-01 06:40:00 | 1.2   |
...
```

Eventually I want to combine the two dataframe as follows by taking the DateTime from DataFrame A and find the row where the datetime is between StartDateTime and EndDateTime:

```
DateTime            | A | Value |
---------------------------------
2020-01-01 06:34:12 | 1 | 1.5   |
2020-01-01 06:36:24 | 2 | 1.2   |
2020-01-01 06:36:28 | 3 | 1.2   |
...
```

I am using the following but it is extremely slow:

```
df_a['Value'] = df_a['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: df_b.loc[(df_b['StartDateTime'] <= x) & (df_b['EndDateTime'] > x)]['Value'].iloc[0])
```

How should I rewrite this as I have dataframe of 1MM+ rows and it is currently extremely slow.

Comment: Are the bins in DataFrame B always 5 minutes apart?

Comment: It seems to be - but I want to keep things more flexible in case it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Case 1: the bins are variable sizes

In this case, the best I could think of is using `pd.cut`:

```
mapper = pd.Series(df_b['Value'])
mapper.index = df_b['StartDateTime']

cutoffs = df_b['StartDateTime'].copy()
cutoffs[cutoffs.index.max() + 1] = df_b['EndDateTime'].max()

bins = pd.cut(df_a['DateTime'], bins=cutoffs)
df_a['Value'] = mapper.loc[pd.IntervalIndex(bins).left].values
```

You create a Series to map the start times to Values.  You then create another Series representing the cutoff points that the times from DataFrame A will be binned into (note that you need to manually add the last end time).  Then you bin the times into those cutoffs with `pd.cut`, and use the `left` value of the bin to `loc` the mapping series.

#### Case 2: the bins are equally sized

It looked like OP's bins were 5 minute chunks.  If that is right, you can exploit that using `pd.Series.dt.floor()` to quickly convert the times from DataFrame A into times that can index DataFrame B:

```
mapper = pd.Series(df_b['Value'])
mapper.index = df_b['StartDateTime']
df_a['Value'] = mapper.loc[df_a['DateTime'].dt.floor('5T')].values
```

#### Timing:

Here's the example data I used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 100 # tweak this to see each option at scale

dr1 = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 06:00:00', freq='5T', periods=size)
dr2 = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 06:05:00', freq='5T', periods=size)
drA = pd.to_datetime({'year':dr1.year, 'month':dr1.month,
                      'day':dr1.day, 'hour':dr1.hour,
                      'minute':np.random.randint(1,60,len(dr1)),
                      'second':np.random.randint(1,60,len(dr1))}).sort_values()
drA = drA[drA < dr2.max()]

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':drA, 'A':range(len(drA))})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'StartDateTime':dr1, 'EndDateTime':dr2, 'Value':np.random.rand(len(dr2))})
```

Results using `%%timeit` with `size=100`:

- `apply`: 61 ms ± 851 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- `pd.cut`: 8.98 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- `dt.floor`: 865 µs ± 17.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- *Adding @Rik Kraan's answer* with `np.where`*: 1.85 ms ± 7.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

*This answer is much better than my `pd.cut`, but I also got a `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 931. GiB for an array with shape (999999, 1000000) and data type bool` when increasing the `size` up to `1000000`.

So taking the floor is *significantly* faster than the original method.  But if your bins are not equally split, it will not be correct.  You could check this with `df_b['StartDateTime'].dt.minute.unique()`, or `df_b['StartDateTime'].dt.time.unique()`.  It might even be possible to iteratively use multiple floor values, if you could find appropriate ones to use.

The `pd.cut` version is still a marked improvement though; maybe there are some other optimizations that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create two arrays that returns the indices for both `dfs` `A` & `B` where the condition is met (`A['DateTime']` is between `B['StartDateTime']` & `B['EndDateTime']`

```
i, j = np.where(
(A['DateTime'].values[:, None] >= B['StartDateTime'].values) & 
(A['DateTime'].values[:, None] <= B['EndDateTime'].values)
)
```

Select the the rows from dataframes `A` and `B` corresponding to these indices and create a new dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([A.values[i], B.values[j]]),
    columns=A.columns.append(B.columns)
)
```

Comment: I added this to the timings in my answer, and it seems very quick!  But I also got a memory error when increasing the *n*, which I don't quite understand.

Comment: I think that within the np.where a mask is created using numpy broadcasting which is of size `num_rows *num_rows`. Can imagine that this is the reason of the memory error when working with large dataframes. Interesting!